# How to pad an xsd:decimal with zeros?

Tags: xml, soap, cxf

We are using CXF to speak to an external SOAP interface with a bit of a weird bahviour. The interface expects xsd:decimal to be *left* padded with zeros up to 15 digits. So `23` will become `000000000000023`.

How can I achieve this padding with CXF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. I created an XmlJavaTypeAdapter for this, which I then use via the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation.

```
public class XmlDecimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter< String, BigDecimal > 
{

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   @Override
   public String marshal( BigDecimal value ) throws Exception
   {
      final String  stringRepresentation = value.toString();

      if( value.compareTo( BigDecimal.ZERO ) < 0 ){
         String result = "-00000000000000";
         return result.substring( 0, result.length() - stringRepresentation.length() + 1 ) + stringRepresentation.substring( 1 );
      }
      String result = "000000000000000";
      return result.substring( 0, result.length() - stringRepresentation.length() ) + stringRepresentation;
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   @Override
   public BigDecimal unmarshal( String value ) throws Exception
   {
      if( value.equals( "000000000000000" ) ){
         return BigDecimal.ZERO;
      }   
      if( value.startsWith( "-")  ){
         return new BigDecimal( value.replaceFirst( "^-0*", "-" ) );         
      }
      return new BigDecimal( value.replaceFirst( "^0*", "" ) );         
   }
}
```